# Why was a Prussian soldier in Nova Scotia in 1817?

Tags: prussia, historical-context, military-practices

After participating in the Battle of Waterloo, Private Gottlieb Schmidt was discharged from the 3rd battalion in Halifax, Nova Scotia, in 1817. Private Schmidt was in the 3rd Battalion 60th Regiment. Anyone know why Prussian troops would have been in Nova Scotia?

Comment: Do you have any other information from his discharge papers?

Comment: 60th (Royal American) Regiment? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Royal_Rifle_Corps#Napoleonic_Wars

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct from the following it is clear that although Gottlibe Schidt,  was German, he was however not a German soldier, but and English soldier. Which I think therefore answers your question.

Gottlibe Schidt Born 1761, Death 2 April 1819 aged 58
King's German Legion - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_German_Legion
1. 
The King's German Legion (KGL) was a British Army unit of mostly expatriate German personnel during the period 1803–16. The Legion achieved the distinction of being the only German force to fight without interruption against the French during the Napoleonic Wars. The Legion was formed within months of the dissolution ...
He is also listed on the Waterloo Medal Roll as Private Godfry Schmide 4th Line Battalion King’s German Legion, Regimental no. 2
Royal Hospital Chelsea, 60 Foot King American Regiment, service shows aged 27 discharged date 1816. Birth year 1768. aged 47, 1st Foot Battillon, Born Magdeburg, Prussia.

There were two types of Chelsea Pensioners in pensioners and out pensioners, I am not certain but I suppose that he must have been an in pensioner.

There is also the following volume among others on the Kings German Ligion which may be of interest to you on 
The Longest Afternoon: The 400 Men Who Decided the Battle of Waterloo by Brendan Simms